# page does not reload after return

Tags: javascript, jquery, pageload

when i leave my page by clicking on a link and i want to return to the page, it does not reload anew.

I am autodidact and i do not know anything about javascript but is this maybe because i must make **die** or **clear** javascript when closing the page ? Or the opposite ?

If someone can have a look at my page.

The html : [www.igorlaszlo.com](http://www.igorlaszlo.com)

I use also this .js file : [www.igorlaszlo.com/main/face.js](http://www.igorlaszlo.com/main/face.js)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand the problem. When I click on a link from your homepage, then click the back button, the homepage reloads.  Am I missing something?

Comment: In that case i am missing something ? :) When i click to the "back" arrow of my FF browser, my homepage remains white (no preloader, no content). It happened the same yersterday with a friend of mine in another country...